# How to replace head of spigot without replacing stem?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, outdoor, copper, spigot

I have a leaking outside spigot that has the pipe stem embedded ln a stone wall, with no access to the back. However, there is enough pipe protruding from the wall to cut the copper pipe just behind the old spigot and install a new one. My neighbor mentioned using a pressure-mount spigot. I’m wondering if I can use a Sharkbite, if I need to thread the copper pipe, or if there is another type of pressure fitting I should use? I. Can’t get a plumber to touch this!

Comment: Usually the valve is removable, which is probably what is leaking.  Should be a big nut under the handle.  Use one wrench to hold the spigot and one to turn the nut.  Take it to local plumbing store.

Comment: Agree. Fixing the leaking valve rather than replacing the spigot might be the better approach here.

Comment: Thanks, y’all. I’ll try that instead.